# ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y in seaborn visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a stripplot where size should be a column of the DataFrame. Here is my DataFrame 'counts'.

```
   BPXDI1  BPXSY1  Groups
0     0.0    98.0       2
1     0.0   104.0       1
2     0.0   116.0       1
3     0.0   120.0       1
4     0.0   124.0       1
```

The length of the column Groups and the other columns are exactly the same

```
len(counts.Groups)
```

Output is 1061
Again the length of the DataFrame is also 1061.
But when I try to run this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10), dpi= 80)    
sns.stripplot(counts.BPXDI1, counts.BPXSY1, s=counts.Groups, ax=ax)

plt.title("Stripplot for Systolic vs Diastolic Blood Pressure", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-2e1bd399f6e4> in <module>
      1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10), dpi= 80)
----> 2 sns.stripplot(counts.BPXDI1, counts.BPXSY1, s=counts.Groups, ax=ax)
      3 
      4 plt.title("Stripplot for Systolic vs Diastolic Blood Pressure", fontsize=20)
      5 plt.show()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in stripplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, jitter, dodge, orient, color, palette, size, edgecolor, linewidth, ax, **kwargs)
   2799                        linewidth=linewidth))
   2800 
-> 2801     plotter.plot(ax, kwargs)
   2802     return ax
   2803 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in plot(self, ax, kws)
   1202     def plot(self, ax, kws):
   1203         """Make the plot."""
-> 1204         self.draw_stripplot(ax, kws)
   1205         self.add_legend_data(ax)
   1206         self.annotate_axes(ax)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in draw_stripplot(self, ax, kws)
   1178                 kws.update(c=palette[point_colors])
   1179                 if self.orient == "v":
-> 1180                     ax.scatter(cat_pos, strip_data, **kws)
   1181                 else:
   1182                     ax.scatter(strip_data, cat_pos, **kws)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1436     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1437         if data is None:
-> 1438             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1439 
   1440         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py in wrapper(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    409                          else deprecation_addendum,
    410                 **kwargs)
--> 411         return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
    412 
    413     return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4446         s = np.ma.ravel(s)
   4447         if len(s) not in (1, x.size):
-> 4448             raise ValueError("s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y")
   4449 
   4450         c, colors, edgecolors = \

ValueError: s must be a scalar, or the same size as x and y
```

Can anyone help? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your code works for me too. something is wrong with your seaborn installation or dataframe. please provide your data frame

Answer (score 0):

`size` is a seaborn's option, `s` is not and is passed to `plt.scatter`:

```
 sns.stripplot(counts.BPXDI1, counts.BPXSY1,size=counts.Groups*50)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I changed it to size. but it didn't work for me. Any other tips? @Quang

Comment: Not sure why. It works with your sample data as I showed in the answer. What do you mean by *it didn't work for me*, what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```py
sns.stripplot(counts.BPXDI1, counts.BPXSY1, sizes=counts.Groups, ax=ax)
```